# Use a catkin package in another package

Tags: ros, kinematics, moveit, ros-melodic, trac-ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am on ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04
I have the [trac_ik](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/master/) package in my catkin workspace. When I do `catkin_make`, everything goes well. I have another package `arm_moveit_config` in which I modified the `kinematics_solver` in `kinematics.yaml` from the default `kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin` to `trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin`. But when I run the my program an error pops up at

```
const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group1 = move_group.getCurrentState()->getJointModelGroup(planning_group_);

std::vector<std::string> jointNames = joint_model_group1->getSolverInstance()->getJointNames();
```

which says `The kinematics plugin (arm) failed to load. Error: Could not find library corresponding to plugin trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.  Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group arm`

I know this can be solved if I install trac_ik using `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-trac-ik-kinematics-plugin` but I would like to know where I should modify to get the trac_ik kinematics plugin work

MoveIt's [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/trac_ik/trac_ik_tutorial.html#usage) just says to add the package to the catkin workspace but I find that there could be something missing.

Any help would be really appreciated
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400808/use-a-catkin-package-in-another-package/) by [shyamashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31162/shyamashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-18**:
Ideally it should work out of the box. I am using it with melodic.

by any chance if you have installed anything related to track-IK using apt, it can cause issue. so remove anything do `sudo apt remove ros-melodic-trac-ik*`.

> but I would like to know where I should modify to get the trac_ik kinematics plugin work

To answer your question, [here](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/master/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/trac_ik_kinematics_description.xml) you can rename the solver plugin class name. Which should be same as what you put in the `kinematics.yaml`.

After that can you try building only `track_ik_kinematics_plugin` may be using `catkin build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanks for the reply. I could get it working when I removed the `build` and `devel` folder and redid `catkin_make`

---

Originally posted by [shyamashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31162/shyamashi/) with karma: 66 on 2022-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0